# C++ incorrect average results

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my C++ program. I have to make a simple program which is adding values which user input and sum them and after that calculate the average. The program have to calculate average until user inputs 0.

```
int value;
float sum = 0.0;
int counter = 0;
float average;

cout << "Enter value " << endl;
cin >> value;

while (value != 0)
{
    cout << "Enter value" << endl;
    cin >> value;
    counter++;
    sum += value;
}

average = sum / counter;
cout << "Average = " << average;


return 0;
```

When I introduce 3 + 3 + 2 I'm getting 1.66667 but it should be 2.66667 what I'm doing wrong? Please could someone explain me how the program should work. I can not use here methods but just simple while loop and I don't know how many numbers there would be.

Comment: You're ignoring the first input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write duplicate code like

> ```
> cout << "Enter value " << endl;    ////// 1
> cin >> value;                      ////// 2
> // counter++;      MISSING!
> // sum += value;   MISSING!
>
> while (value != 0)
> {
>     cout << "Enter value" << endl; ////// 1
>     cin >> value;                  ////// 2
>     counter++;
>     sum += value;
> }
> ```

since chances are twice as high to introduce bugs. Instead:

```
 for(;;) // for-ever
 {
     cout << "Enter value: ";
     if(!(cin >> value) || value == 0)
         break;

     counter++;
     sum += value;
 }
```

Plan-B (shorter):

```
 while(cout << "Enter value: ",
       (cin >> value) && value != 0) {
     counter++;
     sum += value;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the while loop like this

```
while (value != 0)
{
    counter++;
    sum += value;
    cout << "Enter value" << endl;
    cin >> value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because the first input from the user is missed in calculating the `sum` of all the values entered by the user due to the way you wrote the code:

```
cout << "Enter value " << endl;
cin >> value;  // first user input

while (value != 0)
{
    cout << "Enter value" << endl;
    cin >> value;  // This override the first user input
    counter++;
    sum += value;  // The first input never make it to this summation
}
```

Moreover, you will get output `nan` if the user enters `0` as the first input because in that particular case you program is doing divide by zero:

```
average = sum / counter; //counter is initialized with 0
```

For this type of cases, `do-while` loop is more suitable. You can do:

```
int value;
float sum = 0.0f;
int counter = 0;
float average = 0.0f;

do {
    cout << "Enter value:" << endl;
    cin >> value;
    if (value != 0) {
        counter++;
        sum += value;
    }
} while (value != 0);

if (counter > 0) {
    average = sum / counter;
}
cout << "Average = " << average << endl;
```